# Nested list binding doesn't work

Tags: nancy

Recent NancyFX has support for list binding https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding but it didn't work for me.

For collection model binding test I created a stackoverflow-like Question model:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I bind it like:

```
Post["/question"] = parameters =>
{
    Question question = this.Bind();
    return View["question.html", question];
};
```

In HTML form I tried different things:

```
<form action="/question" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="Question Name" />
            <input type="text" name="Id" value="1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[0].Name" value="Answer 1 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[0].Id" value="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[1].Name" value="Answer 2 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[1].Id" value="2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[2].Name" value="Answer 3 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Answers[2].Id" value="3" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And also:

```
<form action="/question" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="Question Name" />
            <input type="text" name="Id" value="1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][0].Name" value="Answer 1 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][0].Id" value="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][1].Name" value="Answer 2 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][1].Id" value="2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][2].Name" value="Answer 3 Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="Question[Answers][2].Id" value="3" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't bind collection of Answers to the Question object while question's Name and Id are binded correctly.

What is wrong with it and how to make this nested collection binded correctly?

Later I'll try binding a collection of comments to both Question and Answer objects.

Answer (score 1):

There does appear to be a bug somewhere.

It doesn't seem to bind the List & List as they are null.

Also if you do this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="Name[0]" value="Question Name" />
      <input type="text" name="Id[0]" value="1" />
      <input type="text" name="Name[1]" value="Question Name2" />
      <input type="text" name="Id[1]" value="2" />
    </li>
<ul>
</form>
```

Then bind with:

```
Post["/"] = parameters =>
    {
        var model = this.Bind<List<Question>>();
        return 200;
    };
```

It will give you 2 items with the correct values.

Once you add the Answers inputs back in it fails to bind the Question.

Please log an issue at the repository - https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues?milestone=&page=1&state=open

If you feel like investigating and sending a pull request even better :)